# BME280 sensor: OSError [Errno 5]

Tags: python, i2c, sensor

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4B along with a BME280 T/P/humidity sensor. I use the [`bme280`](https://pypi.org/project/RPi.bme280/) and [`smbus2`](https://pypi.org/project/smbus2/) Python libraries to interface with the sensor. For a while it worked pretty well, but yesterday I started getting frequent `OSError`s. Here is a bare minimum example that raises the error:

```py
from smbus2 import SMBus

with SMBus(1) as bus:
    bus.pec = 1
    b = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x76, 0xF7, 8)
    print(b)
```

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/****/Tsensor/local/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    b = bus.read_i2c_block_data(0x76, 0xF7, 8)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/****/miniforge3/envs/sensor/lib/python3.11/site-packages/smbus2/smbus2.py", line 617, in read_i2c_block_data
    ioctl(self.fd, I2C_SMBUS, msg)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

The output of `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- 76 --
```

Note that the `OSError` is not always triggered. Sometimes I do get a valid output from this minimal example.

Any idea what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Try tweaking I2C bus frequency.  I have a dtparam=i2c_baudrate=400000 on my pi zero 2w, but you can go lower... Also, i use for same sensor a RPi.bme280 library.

Comment: Setting `i2c_baudrate=100000` (or lower) in `/boot/config.txt` (and rebooting) fixed my issue (mostly). If you repost your comment as a reply, I can mark it as the correct answer for future generations of tinkerers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set

dtparam=i2c_baudrate=100000 (or lower)

in /boot/config.txt

Answer (score 0):

You have a poor I2C connection.  Check that all the pertinent wires are secure and make a good connection.  I.e. check power, ground, SDA, and SCL.

Comment: I replaced the wires and redid the connections several times over, but the problem persists. Could it be a faulty sensor?

Comment: Yes, however a wiring problem is far more likely.  Perhaps add photos clearly showing the connections at the Pi and the sensor ends.

Comment: I find these sensors are often prone to 'crashing' and a power cycle is needed to restore communication

Comment: @joan: I've uploaded some pictures to [here](https://postimg.cc/gallery/jr4gDqJ1).

Comment: @Bra1n: how would one do a power cycle? (I am quite green in this sort of work).

Comment: Other than a manual disconnect/reconnect you could power it from a GPIO pin as the current requirements of the BME280 are modest and toggle the pin when the sensor stops responding